# How to expand your base when there's no links available

Tags: astroneer

I started building straight forward from my spaceship (the part of it which gets you to the planet) and now that I have 4 of them, I can not build anything more, is there anything I could do?

Comment: FWIW i believe you can also build off of a large shuttle, not sure about the small version though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I learned this the hard way yesterday.

When you build a small link (using 1 resin) you can continue to expand from it using additional links. Once you change that small link into a module (by adding 2 resin to it) then you *can no longer create new links from it*. If you have a base with no free links then you will either have to start a new game, or create a Habitat (using your Printer) and start a second base in your current game.

I started a new game and used a long chain strategy, where I created chains from the habitat, and attached modules to the sides of the chain;

```
   M  M     M  M
   |  |     |  |
x--x--x--H--x--x--x
   |  |     |  |
   M  M     M  M
```

H = Habitat
x = small link (1 resin)
M = Module (Printer, Research, Vehicle Bay etc)

As a plus this design also gives you plenty of space on the links to put utility items such as Solar Panels, Batteries and Wind Turbines, without cluttering your modules.

Comment: That's a great example of how it should be organized. We are currently using that structure and works great, specially because of the ability to place solar panels and turbines on the links instead of the modules.

Comment: I found it's possible to create up to 6 links from a single resin hub. But due to link length you can't do two hexagons next to each other. Doubt you need that many stations but if you build two single resin hubs on each side of your landing pod, you can build a total of 10 stations with just those.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should always use resin in order to make more links so you don't have this issue in the future. Anyways, you can fix this (I guess the developers realized we were not that clever to not mess it up) by adding a building that does not need to be linked (a.k.a **Habitat**).

### Habitat

From Astroneer wiki:

> The habitat is a small house-like structure where the player is able
>   to save their game and establish a home base.

Which basically means that it gives you another *spaceship (the part of it which gets you to the planet)* where you have again 4 available links that **MUST be expanded** before anything else.

As any other new building, you'll be able to build it after successfully investigating it.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was built another habitat and linked the vehicle bay of habitat one to the smelter of habitat two via a truck this allowed me more expansion slots and allows power transfer from one to the other.